Furnace won't stay on only when it previously ran/is hot
I have a bit of a weird problem with my Goodman GKS9 furnace (~15 years old): When the furnace is cold (i.e., was not burning for ~1hr), it starts up without problems and heats. When the furnace is still warm (i.e., was burning in the last 10-15 mins), it ignites and burns for a few seconds before shutting down. In that case the control module diagnostic led blinks once, so indicating a "furnace lockout due to excessive number of ignition retries". After the lockout is over after 1hr the furnace starts heating without problems again.
I recently replaced both the igniter and the flame sensor. Based on this description, do you have any idea what could cause this to happen?
Thanks so much!

Strange behavior, but it could be the overheat protection sensor
